# Image is not uploaded to defined folder in node.js

Tags: html, node.js, rest

I have a small HTML template and what I want is to upload image from one location to another. After selecting and clicking on the upload button, response gives me "Uploaded successfully" But the image is not in the destination folder. Please look into the below code.

HTML

```
<form id="frmUploader" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="book/api/Upload/" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="imgUploader" multiple />
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload" onclick="upload()"/>
</form>
```

index.js

```
function upload() {
    axios.post(baseUrlLocal+'/book/api/Upload', {headers: headers})
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.success)
        if (response.data.success) {
            console.log("hi: "+response)
        // $.notify("New Book is Added to your Library", "success");

    }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
            // $.notify("Please check all the details","warn");
        });
}`
```

book.js

```
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, "../public/images/");
},
filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + 
file.originalname);
}
 });

var upload = multer({
storage: Storage
 }).array("imgUploader", 3);



router.get("/image", function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
`router.post("/api/Upload", function(req, res) {
upload(req, res, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.end("Something went wrong!");
    }
    return res.end("File uploaded sucessfully!.");
});
 });`
```

Comment: Where does the image get stored and where did you wanted it to be stored can you please elaborate the issue with your folder structure !

Comment: destination is:../public/images/ . What I want is browse the image from file input and rename it and transfer to above destination

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: image is not found in destination folder although I get success message

Comment: Where is it getting stored?

Comment: its not getting stored anywhere